# First time itself R.java is not getting generated

Tags: android

I have tried all that i could to generate the R.java file but in vain. I have just created an android project and while creating the android project it isn't creating R.java file ! There were compilation errors in my project as i still had to add the android.jar file to my project but even after adding the jar file, cleaning the existing build and again building it didn't work.

Then i checked the 'build automatically' option in eclipse. Even that didn't help !

Few things to be noted :

1)I have created the android project with build-target android 2.2 and API version 8.

2)I would like to tell is while creating the project it gives an error saying proguard.cfg not found ! I couldn't locate 'default.properties' file to delete the entry which refers to proguard.cfg entry.

3)JAVA_HOME in my environment variables is pointing to jdk1.4. Dunno whether this should be the reason !

4)Contents of

1.main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

2.strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloAndroidActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hello, Android !!</string>
</resources>
```

3.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.pack.android.test"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

4.Code for HelloWorldActivity.java

```
  package com.pack.android.test;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
      }
   }
```

Attached are the images for

[image: Folder structure in eclipse (Eclipse 3.6)]
[image: res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png]
[image: res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png]
[image: res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png]
Please help me out. I have just started with the Hello World application :)

Thanks,
Adithya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R.java might not be generated because you have other errors in your code **not** related to the R file. So check if you have these errors, fix them, and clean your project.

Comment: yes..my android sdk location was wrong..which i corrected..thanks !

Comment: @Adithya - then why do you say *First* time it's not generated? It would *never* generate.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated the SDK as well. Get platform-tools and build-tools 22.

Comment: yes, you are correct for me also same issue. i updated the sdk

Answer (score 0):

Simply do **Project -> Clean** in Eclipse